# Spring @Valid and @Validated not working together

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I'm using @Validated and @Valid together for a DTO validation. But the problem is with either group level validation works or attribute level one works. 
Both do not work together.

May I know what is wrong with my code?

```
public class Employee {

    //I want to validate status. It should be either 0 or 1 
     (Active/Inactive). 
    //Also it should not be null both for existing and new record.
    @NotNull(groups = { New.class, Old.class })
    @JsonProperty("emp")
    @Min(0) 
    @Max(1)
    private Integer empStatus;

    ...

    public interface Old {
    }

    public interface New {
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateEmployee(
            @Valid @Validated(Employee.Old.class) @RequestBody Employee empDTO) throws Exception {

            ...
}
```

When I only keep @Validated annotation @NotNull check works fine but the min, the max check fails
When I only keep @Valid min, max check works fine but @NotNull does not work

When I keep both only min, max check works but @NotNull does not work.

How can I fix the code to make all validation work fine?

Comment: Adding both it pretty much useless. Only 1 will be evaluated (I suspect first one wins, the other is ignored). But why a validation group in the first place? Judging from the comment it always applies. So either make it always apply or add additional `@Max` annotations with a `group` defined.

Comment: Well, the reason to use groups is this employee DTO has some fields which are expected to be NOT null for existing records, whereas it can be null for new records.

Comment: I managed to fix it by passing the group name in Min and Max annotations. Also, used on Validated at controller later.

 @Min(value=0, message="Value must be between 0 and 1.", groups = { New.class, Old.class})